# Svelte `node scripts/setupTypeScript.js` gives 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, svelte

I am in a `Svelte` project and I have an issue:

- My files are showing no errors in VSCode, but when executing `npm run dev --` all Typescript syntax are shown as error and the server won't start.

So I tried removing all node_modules and reinstalling them, but now when I run `node scripts/setupTypeScript.js` I have the following error:

```bash
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\(...)\my-app\scripts\setupTypeScript.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

I tried reinstalling TypeScript globally (`npm install typescript@latest -g`), but that didn't help. I didn't find anyone with the same issue...

-- Note that it was working perfectly fine, until I did something I don't recall (trying to write something but it was received as shortcut and tampered with my files - I couldn't find anything special in the diff from the git repo, except `package.json` some version (TS related) were upgraded.)

#### Edit

**(Before to reproduce my mistakes, please look below at the answer.)**

So apparently the `./scripts/` folder should exists and doesn't. So i recreated it :

```bash
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
npx degit sveltejs/template svelte-typescript-app
cp -r svelte-typescript-app/scripts ../
cd ../
rm -r tmp
```

But running it now gives me another error that I didn't have before:

```
> node scripts/setupTypeScript.js
node:internal/fs/utils:344
    throw err;
    ^

    at Object.renameSync (node:fs:980:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\(...)\my-app\scripts\setupTypeScript.js:44:4)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'rename',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'C:\(...)\my-app\src\\main.js',
  dest: 'C:\(...)\my-app\src\\main.ts'
}
```

Actually it is trying to convert main.js into main.ts, but because I already run it, it doesn't work.
So I renamed it back into `main.js` and it was successful, but now running `npm run dev --` gives me an error about `Error: Identifier 'sveltePreprocess' has already been declared`, indeed, it appears twice in `rollup.config.js`, just removing the redundancy solves the issue. Warning: There are other duplicated lines.

#### Conclusion

In the end I still have the syntax error popping up, and the `scripts/` directory disappeared again.
See the answer below

Comment: Does `scripts/setupTypeScript.js` exist? The error says it doesn't.

Comment: The folder doesn't exist but as far as I know the folder didn't exist before and it was working still. Could it be somewhere else ?

Comment: So Executing this script a second time was not the solution, and was more a bad idea. It didn't solve my original issue, so I made another post about it, if you want to help : https://stackoverflow.com/q/72841684/17965313

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for those in the same situation, here is the detailled explanation:

- The `setupTypeScript.js` is not working because the directory `scripts/` is missing.
- If you already ran it, the script automatically deleted itself, and its folder. (reason why it's missing...)
- Fact is, that **you should not re-run the script `setupTypeScript.js` a second time**, if you already ran it.
- If you are not sure if you already ran it, check the file `main.js/ts` if it is named : `main.ts` the script `setupTypeScript.js` has probably already been run.
- If you think you didn't execute the script `setupTypeScript.js` and you need to do it but don't have it, then you can download it like this

```bash
npx degit sveltejs/template/scripts scripts
```

If your main is already named `main.ts`, it will throw an error (`at Object.renameSync (node:fs:980:3)`) then, rename it to `main.js`.
If you already ran the script, it will duplicate some lines in `rollup.config.js`, make sure : `import sveltePreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';` and `import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';` are not duplicated.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

it looks as if this path (scripts/setupTypeScript.ts) doesn't exist. Are you running the node command in the folder that contain the scripts folder?

Comment: The folder doesn't exist but as far as I know the folder didn't exist before and it was working still.  It seems to be part of svelte, could it be somewhere else (in the system Node's directory or so) ?